# Why is list.append(x) more efficient than list += l[x]?

Tags: python, list

Appending to list can be possibly done in two ways:

1)

```
mat = []
for i in range(10):
    mat.append(i)
```

or

2)

```
mat = []
for i in range(10):
    mat += [i]
```

From the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> The method append() shown in the example is defined for list objects; it adds a new element at the end of the list. In this example it is equivalent to result = result + [a], but more efficient.

The documentation suggests that approach 1 is more efficient. Why is it so?

Comment: but i suggest `mat = [i for i in range(10)]`

Comment: yes. that is also true. so which among the possible approaches is more efficient?

Comment: Or even just `mat = list(range(10))`. A list comprehension is generally preferred over an explicit loop, but some situations (complicated filtering, or building multiple lists at a time) favor a loop.

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion-based. Although I prefer `.append` looks more readable to me

Comment: @Altoyr: It's not at all, you can see the produced bytecode to know which method is more efficient, which is the question.

Comment: @chepner No the question was not in the generation of a list, but in appending to a list.

Comment: @apt-getinstallhappyness You're starting with an empty list; it's the same thing. In any case, you can always generate the extension using a list comprehension, then add that to the original list with `extend`. There are *many* options, and which (if any) is superior depends other factors.

Comment: @Altoyr Nope. This is not POB. If the question was *Should I use this or this*, then it would have been.  But this is asking *Why is this faster than that*. I hope you got the point :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though using `.append` requires a method  call it's actually slightly more efficient than using the augmented assignment operator, `+=`.

But there's an even better reason to use `.append`: you can do it when the list you're appending to isn't in the local scope, since it's just calling the method of an object in an outer scope, whereas you cannot perform assignments on objects that aren't in the local scope unless you declare them as global (or nonlocal), a practice which is generally best to avoid.

Here's an example:

```
mat = []

def test_append():
    for i in range(10):
        #mat += [i]
        mat.append(i)

def test_iadd():
    for i in range(10):
        mat += [i]

test_append()
print(mat)
test_iadd()
print(mat)
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./qtest.py", line 29, in <module>
    test_iadd()
  File "./qtest.py", line 25, in test_iadd
    mat += [i]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mat' referenced before assignment
```

Of course, we can pass `mat` as an argument to the function:

```
mat = []

def test_append():
    for i in range(10):
        #mat += [i]
        mat.append(i)

def test_iadd2(mat):
    for i in range(10):
        mat += [i]

test_append()
print(mat)
test_iadd2(mat)
print(mat)
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

One reason that `test_iadd2` is slower is that it has to construct a new `[i]` list on *every* loop.

FWIW, here's the bytecode:

```
test_append
 21           0 SETUP_LOOP              33 (to 36)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                19 (to 35)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

 23          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (mat)
             22 LOAD_ATTR                2 (append)
             25 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             31 POP_TOP             
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   35 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE        

test_iadd2
 26           0 SETUP_LOOP              33 (to 36)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                19 (to 35)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

 27          19 LOAD_FAST                0 (mat)
             22 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             25 BUILD_LIST               1
             28 INPLACE_ADD         
             29 STORE_FAST               0 (mat)
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   35 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above bytecode dump was produced using the [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module:

```
from dis import dis

mat = []

def test_append():
    for i in range(10):
        #mat += [i]
        mat.append(i)

def test_iadd2(mat):
    for i in range(10):
        mat += [i]

print('test_append')
dis(test_append)

print('\ntest_iadd2')
dis(test_iadd2)
```

Comment: "Even though using `.append` requires a method call it's actually slightly more efficient than using the augmented assignment operator, `+=`." The question is _why_ is `append` more efficient then `+=`. Provide sources that support this claim.

Comment: @VincentSavard: Fair comment, although the main focus of my answer is that there's another reason _apart from efficiency_ why the use of `.append` is to be preferred. But I hope the additions to my answer have addressed your concerns, to a degree.

Comment: It did, I think it's a much better answer in the context of the question. I upvoted you.

Comment: @PM2Ring, how you can get bytecode?

Comment: @mrvol: Sorry, I'll add that info to my answer.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you! That's cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit('for i in range(10): mat.append(i)', 'mat = []')
1.798893928527832
timeit.timeit('for i in range(10): mat += [i]', 'mat = []')
2.547478199005127
```

method `append` is faster, because it does't use any type conversion.

Comment: `+=` doesn't use any type conversion either.

Comment: Shouldn't you invert the two statements called by `timeit`? First you create an empty list and then you append elements to it...

Comment: @pacholik mat += [i] it's equivalent mat.extend(list(i)). You can check it to try run `mat += i`

Comment: @toti08 No, it isn't. `timeit` create a new empty scope, which defined by second statement `'mat = []'`. If i understand you correctly...

Comment: @mrvol And where is the type conversion in that?

Comment: @pacholik, `mat += [i]` is type conversion. `i` has type integer before assign, and in moment assign its type is list, because `[i]` is equivalent `list(i)`

Comment: @mrvol type `type(i)` before and after.

Comment: @pacholik I've done. Why do you do it? http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_tkEl1qUw9e_0.py

Comment: Ok, time to end this conversation, I'm clearly wasting my time here...

Answer (score 0):

The second is slower because it creates a new list (which is somewhat slow operation).